# How can I run the current test with a keybinding in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2?

Tags: intellij-idea

Recently upgraded to IDEA 2018.2

In previous versions of IDEA, I was able to bind `Run configuration...` to a key (`ctrl-shift-F10` is what I used) in order to run the current test ("current" meaning the test that my editor cursor was inside).

Note that the functionality itself still exists, you can right-click on test name and select "Run" and it will run that test.

But I can't figure out how to map that functionality to a keyboard now - does anyone know the new way?

---

**EDIT:**
The answer below is correct, but be aware that you might need to restart IDEA to pick up the new key mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind a keyboard shortcut of your choice to the action `Run context configuration`.

If you go to the keymap settings and search for that you should be able to set the keyboard config of your choice and be able to run the current test.
Keep an eye of conflicting keyboard shortcuts (inside and outside intellij!)

Comment: This is the right action.  But it wasn't working for me at first (was just re-running most recent spring-boot application in the new run-dashboard).  I had to restart IDEA, then it works like I want.  Not sure what's going on there - first time I've ever had to restart IDEA to pick up new key mappings, hope that's not a trend.  There were other things mapped to the same key before I started doing this, but I had removed them before trying to bind "run context".  Maybe it's a bug with un-binding/re-binding.

Comment: Could be, feel free to report an issue on their issue tracker if you find yourself in the same position again: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA